# Does nginx consider a page request as one request or more (including static files)?

Tags: nginx, connection, rate-limiting

Lets say we have a configuration as below:

```
http {
       limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit1:12m;
       limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=conn_limit2:24m;
       [...]
       server {
           [...]
           location / {
               limit_conn conn_limit1 5;
               limit_conn conn_limit2 200;
           }
} }
```

I have a connection limitation per `IP` and `Host`. My question is when user request for example: `http://www.test.com/index.php`, inside of this we include many `js` `img` files which are logged inside of access_log as a single request!

Does `Nginx` limit connections to 5 for that single request or including all those files that are requested? If there are 6 files inside of that `index.php` then client receives `503` or not?

Comment: You're including many files and these get somehow (?) combined into one request in `access_log`? Could you show an example? Curious how this looks like..

Comment: @gf_ , no each has its own log inside of nginX.

Comment: So, let's say you're including ten files inside your `index.php`, you get ten lines for these files inside your log, when requesting `index.php`, right?

Comment: @gf_, yes that's right. Now I want to know if those 10 requests is related to this connection limit or not

Comment: AFAIK this depends how the client handles the connection(s) and the involved protocol: http/1.1, http/2, spdy etc. (Besides: If you're requesting ten files, this is not a single request, but ten.) Just as a pointer: To limit requests  you could use [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) module.

Comment: The other files are requested inside of index.php, does that mean different requests for nginx?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35226/discussion-between-alireza-hos-and-gf).